# Set UIBarButtonItem's background color working with Storyboard swift

Tags: swift, uikit, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem, iboutlet

I know that this has been asked really often, but I couldn't find anything about doing this with an `IBOutlet`.

I have already found some code how to set the background color of an `UIBarButtonItem` when you create it with code. But I have implemented many connections from the UIBarButtonItem I created in the `Storyboard`.

Is it possible to set the background color and the corner radius of  a *Storyboard-UIBarButtonItem*? And if it is, please write me how.

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, drag and drop a `UIButton` to `UINavigationBar`. Then from **Document Outline** select the `UIButton` which is a child of `UIBarButtonItem`.

[image]

Now go to **Identity Inspector** from the right panel. Here in **User Defined Runtime Attributes** section you can set `backgroundColor`, `cornerRadius` etc. of `UIButton`.

[image]

But the modification does not reflect in Storyboard. Run your project and you can see the changes.

[image]